# Build Failure While trying to build App using Sencha Cmd

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2, extjs-mvc, sencha-architect

I am new to sencha cmd as per the documentation I am able to generate the application structure but when i start to build the app using sencha app build, Iam facing the following excpetion.

```
[ERR]
[ERR] BUILD FAILED
[ERR] com.sencha.exceptions.ExProcess: Failed creating background process
[ERR] onDevelopments\ExtJsProjects\Test\build\temp\production\Test\sass"): Creat
eProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
[ERR]
[ERR] Total time: 19 seconds
[ERR] The following error occurred while executing this line:
E:\Softwares & Frameworks\MyApplicationDevelopments\ExtJsProjects\Test\.sencha\a
pp\build-impl.xml:284: The following error occurred while executing this line:
E:\Softwares & Frameworks\MyApplicationDevelopments\ExtJsProjects\Test\.sencha\a
pp\sass-impl.xml:155: The following error occurred while executing this line:
E:\Softwares & Frameworks\MyApplicationDevelopments\ExtJsProjects\Test\.sencha\a
pp\sass-impl.xml:176: com.sencha.exceptions.ExProcess: Failed creating backgroun
d process
```

I am able to find the file in specified loacation. Kindly help me ..

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because Ruby and Compass are not installed on the system. I used steps described in the following link to fix this issue on my Linux RHEL:
https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/install-ruby-sass-and-compass/
Hope it helps.